# How to prevent user to type more than 2 digits using JavaScript and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a textbox that holds "From" month. (allows values between 1 and 12 only)

How could I prevent users so that when they try to type 3rd character, javascript would prevent users from typing more than 2 digits?

Here is what I have tried so far but I am not able to get desired result(following script does not work at all)

```
    $("#monthFromTextBox").bind("change", function (event) {
        var regex = /^\d{1,2}$/g;
        var monthFrom = $(this).find(".monthFrom").text();
        var yearFrom = $(this).find(".yearFrom").text();
        var monthTo = $(this).find(".monthTo").text();
        var yearTo = $(this).find(".yearTo").text();

        // Allow only 1 or 2 digits only
        if (regex.test(monthFrom) === false) {
            event.preventDefault();
            // alert("Month From value should have 1 or 2 digits only");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: No need to use such complicated logic, a simple attribute on the input element will do `maxlength` like esailija has posted.

Comment: This isn't really going to validate the input if that's what you're going for. They could still enter something like "15" for the month

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<input type="text" maxlength="2">
```

Comment: rlemon, why depend on javascript when you can get it done with html ?

Comment: @rlemon: it's ok Esailija's answer solved the question ;)   but cannot mark it as an answer within 10 minutes

Comment: umm, he doesn't *need* Javascript.

Answer (score 8):

for the luls... if you really wanted a JS answer..

```
$("#monthFromTextBox").on('keydown', function() {
    if (this.value.length > 1) {
        return false;
    }
});​
```

Comment: I think you should use `if ($(this).val().length > 1)`

Comment: lol... my bad. it isn't a troll answer :P it's valid... just not needed.

Comment: I think this is a valid answer as well for me. I could use rlemon's logic to prevent users to enter invalid months or years.

Comment: This is less pointless than you think - `maxlength` doesn't work if your input has `type=number`, so an approach like this is helpful for limiting the number of digits the user can type.

Comment: Unfortunately, though, it's wrong - this also prevents the user from *deleting* characters with the delete or backspace keys once they've hit the max length, which is plainly undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for a JavaScript solution but I don't think you need one.

Why not simply restrict the text box in HTML:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="2" size="10" value="" name="monthFromTextBox">
```

This way, you're covered even if JavaScript's turned off.

Just remember to verify it server-side too if it's an important restriction.